# How to cut link in python?

Tags: python, regex, url

I have the following link:

```
http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51JXXb2vpDL._SY344_PJlook-inside-v2,TopRight,1,0_SH20_BO1,204,203,200_.jpg
```

How to take just this one part of the link:

```
http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51JXXb2vpDL.jpg
```

and remove everything else? I also want to keep the extension.

I want to remove this part:

```
._SY344_PJlook-inside-v2,TopRight,1,0_SH20_BO1,204,203,200_
```

and keep this part:

```
http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51JXXb2vpDL.jpg
```

How can I do this in python?

Comment: And what is the pattern you are looking for here? Anything past the initial letters and digits up to the extension? Or do you need to look for the `._SY` start? One example does not a pattern make.

Comment: What extensions should be supported? Just `.jpg` or are `.png` and `.gif` options too, etc. You need to tell us more about the input here.

Comment: Right there is that it can be jpg, png, gif. In 99% is jpg but I can not be sure will jpg to 100%

Answer (score 1):

You could use:

```
re.sub(r'\._[\w.,-]*(\.(?:jpg|png|gif))$', r'\1', inputurl)
```

This makes some assumptions but works on your input. The search starts at the `._` sequence, takes anything after that that is a letter, digit, dash, underscore, dot or comma, then matches the extension. I picked an explicit small group of possible extensions; you could also just use `(\.w+)$` at the end instead to widen the acceptable extensions to word characters.

Demo:

```
>>> import re
>>> inputurl = 'http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51JXXb2vpDL._SY344_PJlook-inside-v2,TopRight,1,0_SH20_BO1,204,203,200_.jpg'
>>> re.sub(r'\._[\w.,-]*(\.(?:jpg|png|gif))$', r'\1', inputurl)
'http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I51JXXb2vpDL.jpg'
```

Comment: The problem is that in this link to contain the '._' and then I cut the part I need.

Comment: @Krasimir: added the `\._` test for you.

Answer (score 1):

The following should work:

```
import re

url = "http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51JXXb2vpDL._SY344_PJlook-inside-v2,TopRight,1,0_SH20_BO1,204,203,200_.jpg"

print re.sub(r"(https?://.+?)\._.+(\.\w+)", r'\1\2', url)
```

The above code prints

```
http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51JXXb2vpDL.jpg
```

**An important detail:** More links are necessary to find the correct pattern. I'm currently assuming you want everything until the first `._`

Comment: The problem is that in this link to contain the '._' and then I cut the part I need.

Comment: @Krasimir Could you explain yourself? I didn't understand what you meant.

Comment: If here: '51JXXb2vpDL' is present '._' '51JXX._b2vpDL' then regex not working.

Comment: Still don't understand. Please, give me a concrete link from Amazon to understand what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

```
url = "http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51JXXb2vpDL._SY344_PJlook-inside-v2,TopRight,1,0_SH20_BO1,204,203,200_.jpg"
l = url.split(".")
print(".".join(l[:-2:])+".{}".format(l[-1]))
```

prints

```
http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51JXXb2vpDL.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

```
url = re.sub("(/[^./]+)\.[^/]*?(\.[^.]+)$", "\\1\\2", url)
```